# Safari jQuery animate position and width

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-animate

When I click on the button the div should change its width and position. Everything works perfectly on all browsers, except Safari. In safari, the animation is not smooth, first it goes to the left, and then changes its width.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.button').click(function() {

            $('#cosmos').find('#earth').animate({
                width: '400px',
                left: 0,
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                duration: 400,
                queue: true
            });
        });
    });
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EesLm/

Comment: You have entered the value in "%" if you would have entered something like 30px then just giving a 0 will work. you must provide the value in the same way you are using in the style sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be some weird behavior of Safari, but adding the unit will fix it:

```
left: '0%',
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/aq5QR/)

Comment: You forget to talk about the price?! ;)